# Hive inserting values to an array complex type column

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am unable to append data to tables that contain an array column using insert into statements; the data type is array < varchar(200) >

Using jodbc I am unable to insert values into an array column by values like :

```
INSERT INTO demo.table (codes) VALUES (['a','b']);
```

does not recognises the "[" or "{" signs.

Using the array function like ...

```
INSERT INTO demo.table (codes) VALUES (array('a','b'));
```

I get the following error using array function:

```
Unable to create temp file for insert values Expression of type TOK_FUNCTION not supported in insert/values
```

Tried the workaround...

```
INSERT into demo.table (codes) select array('a','b');
```

unsuccessfully:

```
Failed to recognize predicate '<EOF>'. Failed rule: 'regularBody' in statement
```

How can I load array data into columns using jdbc ?

Answer (score 6):

My Table has two columns: `a STRING, b ARRAY<STRING>`.

When I use @Kishore Kumar Suthar's method, I got this:

`FAILED: ParseException line 1:33 cannot recognize input near '(' 'a' ',' in statement`

**But I find another way, and it works for me:**

```
INSERT INTO test.table 
SELECT "test1", ARRAY("123", "456", "789") 
FROM dummy LIMIT 1;
```

`dummy` is any table which has atleast one row.

Answer (score 2):

make a `dummy` table which has atleast `one row`.

```
INSERT INTO demo.table (codes) VALUES (array('a','b')) from dummy limit 1;

hive> select codes demo.table;
OK
["a","b"]
Time taken: 0.088 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Comment: Could you please specific what dummy table need to contain?

Comment: dummy table is a simply a demo table which have atleast one row.

Comment: I created a dummy table with two STRING fields and used the command `INSERT INTO ADS (pageid,adid_list) VALUES ( 'front_page',array(1,2,3)) FROM DUMMY LIMIT 1;`  and got the error : `FAILED: ParseException line 1:16 cannot recognize input near '(' 'pageid' ',' in statement` . Can you help here!!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I have a table employee containing the fields **ID** and **Name**.

I create another table employee_address with fields **ID** and **Address**. Address is a complex data of type **array(string)**.

Here is how I can insert values into it:

```
insert into table employee_address select 1, 'Mark', 'Evans', ARRAY('NewYork','11th 
avenue') from employee limit 1;
```

Here the table employee just acts as a dummy table. No data is copied from it. Its schema may not match employee_address. It doesn't matter.

Comment: Limit 1 means data will be entered once in employee_address.