# How to insert into Hive table with a column of data type array<struct<int>>

Tags: arrays, hadoop, hive, hql, avro

I am trying to insert data into a table in Hive I created.  I’ve been struggling, so I’m trying to simplify it as much as possible to get to the root of the issue.

Here is my simplified code for creating a basic table.  I basically have an array of structure with a single element.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo.S_FILE_PA_JOB_DATA_T;

CREATE TABLE foo.S_FILE_PA_JOB_DATA_T
  PARTITIONED BY (customer_id string)
  STORED AS AVRO
  TBLPROPERTIES (
 'avro.schema.literal'=
 '{
   "namespace": "com.foo.oozie.foo",
   "name": "S_FILE_PA_JOB_DATA_T",
   "type": "record",
   "fields":
   [
      {"name":"pa_hwm"             ,"type":{
         "type":"array",
         "items":{
           "type":"record",
           "name":"pa_hwm_record",
           "fields":
           [
             {"name":"pa_axis"           ,"type":["int","null"]}
           ]
         }
      }}
   ]
   }');
```

My problem is I can’t figure out the syntax to insert into the table.

```
insert into table foo.s_FILE_PA_JOB_DATA_T partition (customer_id) values (0,'a390c1cf-4ee5-4ab9-b7a3-73f5f268b669')
```

The `0` needs to somehow be an `array<struct<int>>` but I can't get the syntax right.  Can anyone help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't directly do that. See also [Hive inserting values to an array complex type column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30446601/hive-inserting-values-to-an-array-complex-type-column).

In theory, you should be able to do it using something like

```
insert into table s_file_pa_job_data_t partition(customer_id)  
  values (array(named_struct('pa_axis',0)) );
```

that is, using the `array()` and `named_struct()` udfs  which will from some scalar values construct respectively an array, and a struct according to your specs. (see UDF documentation here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-ComplexTypeConstructors

but unfortunately if you do that you'll get

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10293]: Unable to create temp file 
for insert values Expression of type TOK_FUNCTION not supported in insert/values
```

because unfortunately hive does not support the use of UDF functions in the `VALUES` clause yet. As the other posts suggest, you could do it using a dummy table, which is kind of ugly, but works.